# How to subset a dataframe using a column from another dataframe in r?

Tags: r

I have 2 dataframes

Dataframe1:
    |    Cue     |  Ass_word | Condition |  Freq   |   Cue_Ass_word  |

---

1  |  ACCENDERE | ACCENDINO  |    A      |     1   |   ACCENDERE_ACCENDINO

2  |  ACCENDERE  | ALLETTARE |    A      |     0   |   ACCENDERE_ALLETTARE

3  |  ACCENDERE  |  APRIRE   |    A      |     1   |   ACCENDERE_APRIRE

4  |  ACCENDERE  | ASCENDERE |    A      |     1   |   ACCENDERE_ASCENDERE

5  |  ACCENDERE  | ATTIVARE  |    A      |     0   |   ACCENDERE_ATTIVARE

6  |  ACCENDERE  |    AUTO   |    A      |     0   |   ACCENDERE_AUTO

7  |  ACCENDERE  | ACCENDINO |    B      |     2   |   ACCENDERE_ACCENDINO

8  |  ACCENDERE| ALLETTARE    |    B      |     3   |   ACCENDERE_ALLETTARE

9  |  ACCENDERE| ACCENDINO    |    C      |     2   |   ACCENDERE_ACCENDINO

10 |  ACCENDERE| ALLETTARE    |    C      |     0   |   ACCENDERE_ALLETTARE

Dataframe2:
     |      Group.1     |  x

---

1    | ACCENDERE_ACCENDINO | 5

13   |   ACCENDERE_FUOCO | 22

16   |    ACCENDERE_LUCE | 10

24   | ACCENDERE_SIGARETTA | 6

....

I want to exclude from Dataframe1 all the rows that contain words (Cue_Ass_word) that are not reported in the column Group.1 in Dataframe2.

In other words, how can I subset Dataframe1 using the strings reported in Dataframe2$Group.1?

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear what you mean, but is this what you need?

```
Dataframe1[!(Dataframe1$Cue_Ass_word %in% Dataframe2$Group1),]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm sorry if my ques is not clear. I'll try to explain better.

I have two dataframe and I want a third one that include all the variable of dataframe1 but limited to the cases indicated in dataframe2

Thus if nrow(dataframe1) is 16345 and norw(dataframe2) is 645 I expect that nrow(dataframe3) == nrow(dataframe2).

Unfortunally if I use the code that you suggest, nrow(dataframe3) == nrow(dataframe1).